# Autofilter matching criteria, all data in the table is copy

Tags: excel, vba

Whenever there is no data matching Autofilter criteria all data is copied. How can I tell Excel not to copy in this case ?

Public Sub autofilter2()

> PO's Not Received

`LastRowExploded_JE1 = Sheets("Exploded JE").ListObjects("Exploded_JE").Range.Rows.Count + 5`

> Copy BU + Object

```
Sheets("PO's Not Received").Select
Columns("M:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
 ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table8").Range.AutoFilter Field:=20, Criteria1:= _
    "To Accrue"
lastrow = Sheets("PO's Not Received").ListObjects("Table8").Range.Rows.Count
Range("M2:N" & lastrow).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
```

> Paste new data

```
Sheets("Exploded JE").Select
Range("L" & LastRowExploded_JE1).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Comment: Honestly I don't know, if there is actually a way to solve this using the autofilter. However, if you nest it into an if, which tests with the worksheetfunction `COUNTIF` you could probably handle the problem: 
`If (WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("Table8"), "To Accrue") >= 1) Then
 ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table8").Range.AutoFilter Field:=20, Criteria1:= _
    "To Accrue"
LastRow = Sheets("PO's Not Received").ListObjects("Table8").Range.Rows.Count
Range("M2:N" & LastRow).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Else
'do nothing
End if`

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting, still learning ;)